# Node API, choosing an endpoint based on content-type in middleware function

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, url, let

I have an endpoint `analysis` in my Node/Express API that accepts JSON requests and currently have a middleware function that checks if `content-type=application/json` or returns an error. I added another endpoint called `analysis/csv` which can accept a csv with multer and requires `content-type=multipart/form-data`. I'm trying to basically have the user call the same endpoint `analysis` and then choose between them based on the content-type. I tried using res.redirect(analysis + /csv) but I get an error `Can't set headers after they are sent`. There is another middleware function after that checks for authentication before finally hitting up the endpoint itself.

My code so far:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  let url: string = req.originalUrl;
  let endpoint: string = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  let multiEndpoints: string[] = ['analysis', ...];

  if (req.get('content-type') != 'application/json' && multiEndpoints.includes(endpoint)) {
    if (req.get('content-type') != 'multipart/form-data') {
      // Send an error that content type must be application/json
    }
    else {
      // I want to redirect to endpoint + /csv here
      next();
    }
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: `Can't set headers after they are sent`

After redirecting, you are looking for next. You don't need to call next when you redirect. You can update it like this:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
let url: string = req.originalUrl;
let endpoint: string = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
let multiEndpoints: string[] = ['analysis', ...];

if (req.get('content-type') != 'application/json' && 
 multiEndpoints.includes(endpoint)) {
if (req.get('content-type') != 'multipart/form-data') {
  // Send an error that content type must be application/json
}
else {
  // I want to redirect to endpoint + /csv here
  // next(); remove this line
  res.redirect('/myRoute')
}
}
else {
next();
 }
});
```

after doing redirect make sure you don't call next